# How to override EditorFor layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

How to override EditorFor layout? For example if i want to render some text before or after editor field.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`EditorFor` is an extension method defined on `HtmlHelper` class. if you want to override it you have to subclass `HtmlHelper`. according to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474074/overriding-extension-methods) overriding extension methods is a bad idea. Even if you decide to go this way how would you make mvc use subclassed `HtmlHelper` instead of default one. your best bet could be overloading `EditorFor` method and using it in views instead of default ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code sample to add some text before and after EditorFor.

Step 1: Define field in model class with a specific DataType with a logical sounding custom names like SmallText, CustomName etc. I just used "MyTypeOfField" in this example.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field_Value code is a required field.")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Field Display Name")]
    [DataType("MyTypeOfField")]
    public string MyField { get; set; }
```

Step 2: Create "MyTypeOfField.cshtml" in folder : Views/Shared/EditorTemplates with below code. If EditorTemplates folder is not present, create it.

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<string>
@string.Format("{0, -10}","XXXXXXXXXX") @Html.TextBox("", "", new { style = "width:30px; text-align:right;" }) @string.Format("{0, -10}","1234567890")
```

Hope this helps!